# How to merge two structs with same structure but different content?

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, struct

I have two structs:

```
struct DEF
{
    DEF(std::string,double foo,double);
    ~DEF();
  
     //---- theory's functions ----//
    double V_of_phi(double,double);
    double dV_of_phi(double, double);
    ...
    double metricStartingPoint;
    double scalarStartingPoint;
    ...}


struct R2
{
    R2(std::string,double,double foo);
    ~R2();
   
    //---- theory's functions ----//
    double V_of_phi(double,double);
    double dV_of_phi(double, double);
    ...
    double metricStartingPoint;
    double scalarStartingPoint;
    ...}
```

These structs are used in a class which is templated with respect to which "theory" (struct) is used like this:

```
template<class theoryType>
class STT{
    public:
        STT(String, double, double);
        ~STT();
    private:
        theoryType* theory; //points to theory at study
        theoryType model; //theory model instance
        ...
        }
```

and used like `theory->V_of_phi(...)` inside the class etc.

At the moment I'm instantiating the `model` instance in the `STT` constructor like:

```
template<class theoryType>
STT<theoryType>::STT(String eos_name, double central_density, double coupling):
        model(eos_name,coupling,central_density),
        ...
        {}
```

where `coupling` is only used in `R2` struct and not in `DEF` (hence the `foo` in DEF's constructor) and vice versa for `central_density` which is only used in `DEF`.

Besides the constructor, the two structs have the exact same structure but different content (for example `DEF::V_of_phi` is different than `R2::V_of_phi`).

Is there any way to make this cleaner, instead of making two different structs that have the exact same format but different member function implementations and member variable values?

Comment: Inheritance?  Looks tailor made for this.

Comment: Like `class Theory` and then `class DEF : public Theory` ?

Comment: Something like that, yes.  I suggest you write an answer containing your best effort (you can answer your own question) and invite people to comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cries for applying "strategy design pattern". Please read about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern), or in many available books about "design patterns".

You would basically implement an abstract base class for the strategy and then derive the specific strategies from that. In your terminology this would be the equivalent of "theory".

In the context class (in your example "STT"), you would add a pointer to the strategy's base class. Then you can call the needed functions using runtime polymorphism. In your example you are using static polymorphism using templates. Also possible.

If you read the Wikipedia article, you could even use [composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) instead of inheritance. This has sometimes advantages and follows other OOP principles. But I do not know your requirements, so, I cannot tell.

I made for you an extremely artificial example, to explain what I was writing above. As said, the question does not contain enough information to come up with a complete solution.

Please see:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Strategy {
    virtual double V_of_phi(double, double) = 0;
    virtual double dV_of_phi(double, double) = 0;
};
struct StrategyDEF : public Strategy {
    double V_of_phi(double a, double b) override { return 42 + a + b; }
    double dV_of_phi(double a, double b) override { return 42 - a -b; }
};
struct StrategyR2 : public Strategy {
    double V_of_phi(double a, double b) override { return 42 + 2 * (a + b); }
    double dV_of_phi(double a, double b) override { return 42 - 2 * (a + b); ; }
};

struct ContextSTT {
    Strategy* strategy{};

    double metricStartingPoint{};
    double scalarStartingPoint{};

    double calculateV_of_phi() { return strategy->V_of_phi(metricStartingPoint, scalarStartingPoint); }
    double calculateDV_of_phi() { return strategy->dV_of_phi(metricStartingPoint, scalarStartingPoint); }
};

int main() {
    StrategyDEF strategyDEF{};
    StrategyR2 strategyR2{};

    ContextSTT contextSTTWithDEF{ &strategyDEF, 1, 1};
    ContextSTT contextSTTWithR2{ &strategyDEF, 2, 2 };

    std::cout << contextSTTWithDEF.calculateV_of_phi() << '\t' << contextSTTWithDEF.calculateDV_of_phi() << '\n';
    std::cout << contextSTTWithR2.calculateV_of_phi() << '\t' << contextSTTWithR2.calculateDV_of_phi() << '\n';
```

Comment: Don't really know if creating a base class with only virtual methods would be the best approach here. But I understand your point, and I guess there's not really another way around this, besides using static polymorphism.